# Como fazer o input() parar apos o espaço em vez da quebra de linha em Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou querendo capturar vários numeros nesse formado:

```
2 4 5 3 5 0 4
```

Como quantidade de números indefinido e sem usar uma lista auxiliar, quero usar apenas uma variável

```
for _ in range(0,n):
    num = int(input())
```

Sei apenas criando lista

```
for _ in range(0,q):
    lista +=[int(input().split(' '))]
```

Comment: Mas se os numeros estão no formato `2 4 5 3 5 0 4 ` então `num = int(input())` nunca irá funcionar. O próprio `split` que tem na pergunta já devolve uma lista . Qual é exatamente a duvida ?

Answer (score 2):

Realmente a pergunta está confusa mas se a lista é "infinita", basta ler uma linha inteira e depois separar os elementos:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# recebe cada número de uma só vez.
print('Digite a lista de números separada por espaços, <Enter> finaliza')
entrada = input('=> ')

# separa a string por espaços e converte em uma lista de inteiros.
lista = [ int(i) for i in entrada.split(' ') ]

# imprime a lista, apenas para referência.
print(lista)
```

Comment: se tiver um espaço no começo da entrada, como está na pergunta, esse código quebra -  tem que coloca um filtro "`...if i`` na list-comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

É uma pergunta extremamente confusa e pelo pouco que entendi você quer que ao encontrar um valor `" "` o sistema pare, se não for corrija a pergunta. De qualquer modo segue a solução para o que eu disse:

```
import sys

lista = int(input("Digite a lista"))
newLista = lista.split(' ')

for i in newLista:
    if(i == " "): #Identifica o " "
        sys.exit() #O sistema irá parar
```

Se quiser separar cada termo da lista, terá que utilizar outro `.split()` e outro marcador. Os dados de entrada devem conter tal marcador.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja `capturar` todos os `valores` digitados em uma só linha. Ou seja, você gostaria de implementar um programa que ao `solicitar` a digitação dos valores, o usuário fosse capaz de `digita-los` em uma só linha.

De acordo com o meu entendimento o algoritmo ficaria...

```
valores = list(map(int, input('Digite os valores: ').split()))
print(f'\033[32mValores digitados: {valores}\033[m')
```

Observe o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/gqenmhqf-solkarped).

Observe que para utilizar corretamente este algoritmo, você tem que:

1. Executar o algoritmo;
2. Digitar `todos` os valores na `mesma` linha `separados` por um `espaço`;
3. Pressionar `Enter`.

Observe também, que este algoritmo é capaz de capturar um número `indefinido` de valores.